# The Next and Previous buttons in my project are not working as expected, My code is faulty, but I can't understand why

Tags: java, android

My project on Android is a table generator

It works fine until the next and previous Button, 
like If I input 5 to generate table of 5, it works fine

But when I click next the table changes to 6, but then there's no increment 
and on Previous the table directly shown is of 4 elements instead of 5 and it does not decrement anymore.

Comment: Please, publish your code here

Answer (score 0):

You can save the values within a bundle. Then play around with the values manipulating the bundle.

Comment: Yes This Helps Me